# Change value of session variable in template Django

Tags: django

In Django, I can get the value of a session variable with

```
{{ request.session.variable_name }}
```

How can I change the value of `variable_name` inside a template? Something like

```
{% request.session.variable_name.set(new_value) %}
```

Comment: can I ask why specifically on the template? you could do it more easily in the view

Comment: That's not something you should try to do in a template. Templates should not have side effects. Think of them as a complicated kind of formatting string.

Comment: Since a template must be rendered by a view, I can't think of a reason this want to do this in the template.

Comment: I have the same need of changing this session variable in the template. Reason: by clicking a certain button on the page I should reload the page with the different data (that depends on the button being clicked). Did you succeed in changing the variable value in the template? @Peter DeGlopper  what do you suggest doing if not changing the variable value in the template? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Depends on the details of your situation, but probably either a) have the buttons resubmit the request and use the value in your view to render appropriately or b) use Javascript to update the page on the fly, possibly after retrieving some new information AJAX-style.